# How can you import a Microsoft Word Equation to Microsoft Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been finding ways to move pictures and tables and other things from `Microsoft Word 2010` to `Microsoft Excel 2010`.  What I would like to find a way to do would be to do the same thing with the `OMath` objects, or the Equations.  I would like to keep the equations in their original form as much as possible, so if that means translating the `OMath` objects to a picture (`InlineShape`), then that is what I want to do.

Here is what the equation looks like in Word, and I'd like to import that to excel using VBA:
[image]

Right now, I'm only able to transfer the Range.Text representation of this object, which makes this Equation look like this:

[image]

I have found that I can select this object and do a selection copy.  Is there a way to determine the dimensions of this selection?  I'd like to paste this in a particular cell which is already resized to fit the equation.  I loop through the paragraphs of the Word document, with each paragraphs referred to as `DocPara` and when I come across an equation, I select it like this:

```
DocPara.Range.OMaths(1).Range.Select
With Selection
    .CopyAsPicture
    oWB.ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=oWB.ActiveSheet.Cells(headingCount, 3)
End With
```

The problem with what I have above is that the picture pastes where I want it, but is bigger than the row it is sitting on and if I resize the row, the picture stretches vertically linearly with the row resize.  I need to resize the row I am pasting this image to before I paste.  How can I access the size of the picture I just put on the clipboard?

Does anyone have some ideas?  I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-equation-editor-in-excel-HP010215799.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking at that.  However, I'm trying to get this done in a Macro with an equation that already exists in a word document.  I want to be able to pull the equation from word, where my macro lives, and place it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

After you paste the picture, set its `.Placement` property to `xlMove` (Move with cells, but don't resize) before you resize the row.  This prevents the picture resizing.

This is equivalent to setting the picture format properties

[image]